# Java If Statement

Tags: java, if-statement

I have written some code in Java which tests the fitness of two solutions.

I am looking to then compare the two solutions and keep the one which has the best fitness and to discard the other.

For example:

```
if(fitness1 < fitness2)
    keep fitness1 and discard/ignore fitness2
else
    keep fitness2 and discard/ignore fitness1
```

How would I go about achieving this?  Eventually I hope to have a list (size n) of the best fitness levels.  I imagine that I would have to add the best fitness in each iteration to a list of some type?

Comment: Could you be more specific? What kind of variable is the fitness (int, double, etc.)?

Comment: `fitness1` and `fitness2` are both double variables.  `discard` just means 'ignore' - I am only looking to keep track of the best fitness level.

Comment: This looks like a very very basic Java question. Have you read tutorials about basic Java syntax, especially declaring and assigning variables?

Comment: Are greater or lesser numbers better? Your current comparison would imply that a lower fitness score is better than a higher one (which may very well be the case, of course).

Comment: What kind of data are `fitness1` and `fitness2`? What do you mean by "discard"? Java has automatic garbage collection, so you don't need to do anything to discard an object; just don't keep a reference to it.

Comment: @eldareathis Yes, the lower the fitness score the better as this is a minimisation problem.  Ideally, a fitness score of 0 would be perfect, however this is never truly achievable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd say, create an `ArrayList<Double>` to keep the best values in and use this:

```
arrayList.add((fitness1 < fitness2) ? fitness1 : fitness2);
```

That way you'll have a list of the best values.

Comment: Though I don't see any duplicate results in the example output, could you show what algorithm you're using to go through the possible fitness values?

Answer (score 6):

```
best = (fitness1 < fitness2) ? fitness1 : fitness2;
```

`?:` ternary operator may be useful in this kind of decision making process.

Comment: Which is a convulted and hardly scaling way to reinvent `min`.

Comment: Wish i could +2 this, don't see enough ternary operators in Java :D

Comment: Seems like a baroque way of writing `best = Math.min(fitness1, fitness2);`

Comment: I have C/C++ background and `?:` was made available in Java especially for people like me. I like it and I'm used to it. :) Of course both methods are OK.

Answer (score 1):

If your end goal is to have a list of the "top n fitness levels", you'll probably have a list of them coming in, right?

If that's the case, just leverage the capabilities of List:

```
// takes a list of Doubles, returns 'top' levels
public List<Double> getTopN(List<Double> allLevels, int top) {
    List<Double> sorted = new ArrayList<Double>(allLevels); // defensive copy
    Collections.sort(sorted, new Comparator<Double>() {
        @Override
        public int compare(Double left, Double right) {
            return left.compareTo(right); // assumes no null entries
        }
    });

    return sorted.subList(0, Math.min(sorted.size(), top));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Introduce another variable.

*type* `bestFitness`

```
if(fitness1 < fitness2){
   bestFitness = fitness1;
}else{
   bestFitness = fitness2;
}
```

Then discard both `fitness1`, `fitness2`

Or use [Math.min](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#min%28double,%20double%29)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the fitness is an int

```
int fitness1 = 5;
int fitness2 = 10;

int bestFit = bestFit(fitness1, fitness2);

//nothing needs to be done to explicitly discard fitness2.  Just keep using bestFit
//and let the GC worry about discarding stuff for you

public static int bestFit(int f1, int f2) { 

   return f1 > f2 ? f1 : f2

}
```